# How to match the pattern regardless of the number of whitespaces

Tags: regex

Not good in regexp, how can i match the pattern regardless of how many whitespaces there is?

```
var pattern = / void main$/;  //here

var pool1 = "abdodfo void main";
var pool2 = "abdodfo   void     main";

console.log(pattern.test(pool1)); //  true
console.log(pattern.test(pool2)); //  must also be true
```

Comment: Search and learn about [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the pattern to: `/\s+void\s+main$/`

Comment: this wont match for 'void main'. Can u modify to be true if there is a whitespace or NONE before 'void main'?

Comment: @fireflieslive `/\s*void\s+main$/`

Answer (score 2):

```
var pattern = /void\s+main$/;
```

Use `\s` for whitespace, and `+` for "one or more."

Comment: `\w` for whitespace?? It's `\s`.

Comment: @RohitJain Yep, already edited :P I was trying to answer too quickly :P